# How to pass innerText from a dxTextArea into a function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, textarea, typescript, devextreme

we are using javascript/typescript and have been unable to pass the 'in-putted text' from a `dxTextArea` in a **DevExtreme (Typescript) Project**.

We are using:

```
 <div id="myTextArea" data-bind="dxTextArea: {showClearButton: true,value: 'MyTests'}" ></div>

 <div  data-bind="dxButton: { text: 'Save text' }" onclick="saveMyData(document.getElementById('myTextArea').innerText)"></div>
```

With the function "saveMyData" defined as:

```
<script>
function saveMyData(myData)
{
alert("text is "+myData.innerText);
mytext.innerText += myData.innerText;
}
</script>
```

However, the alert only contains

> text is

---

We have also tried `textContent`, but got the same results.

Anyone got an idea(s) of why this is happening?

there isn't an error on screen, so we don't **think** it's a declaration error.

(N.B. this code has been simplified for demonstration purposes).

---

Below is a link to the 'most helpful/detailed' docs:

[Link to dxTextArea documentation](http://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxTextArea/?version=14_1)

please feel free to ask for clarification/details as I know i'm pretty bad at explaining myself 'on paper'. I would post a fiddle only it doesn't/won't recognise the `dxTextArea` nor `dxButton`, so pretty useless!

**EDIT**

using innerHTML as suggested gives:

[image]

Comment: You have to use `innerHTML` instead of `innerText` and then `alert(myData);`. You are using `document.getElementById('myTextArea').innerHTML` so the text itself is passed to the `saveMyData` function.

Comment: @GuyT - thanks for your suggestion, but this also yields incorrect results: (please see edit in Q)

Comment: Ok, step by step: 1. change `saveMyData(document.getElementById('myTextArea').innerText)` to `saveMyData(document.getElementById('myTextArea').textContent)` 2. Change `function saveMyData(myData)
{
alert("text is "+myData.innerText);
mytext.innerText += myData.innerText;
}
</script>` to `function saveMyData(myData)
{
alert(myData);
}
</script>`

Comment: @GuyT, only the date/time bit works (created/added in script) - the part in the function call must be empty of something - as it returns "" with both **innerText** AND **textContent**

Comment: Do you use the `observable`? From the documentation: `Declare an observable variable and pass it to the value option to update the variable each time widget value changes.`

Comment: Comes up as *undefined* just. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the instance of dxTextArea widget and get value of option `value`

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tabalinas/c4dmsmeL/2/

```
<div id="textArea" data-bind="dxTextArea: { value: 'My value' }"></div>
<div data-bind="dxButton: { clickAction: buttonClick, text: 'Get value' }"></div>

var vm = {
    buttonClick: function() {
        var val = $("#textArea").dxTextArea("instance").option("value");
        alert(val);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

But better to use ko.observable in your view model bound to `value` option of dxTextArea

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tabalinas/c4dmsmeL/

```
<div data-bind="dxTextArea: { value: textAreaValue }"></div>
Text entered: <span data-bind="text: textAreaValue">

var vm = {
    textAreaValue: ko.observable("My value")
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

If you want to play with widget guts, you can do following:
http://jsfiddle.net/tabalinas/c4dmsmeL/3/

```
<div id="textArea" data-bind="dxTextArea: { value: 'My Value' }"></div>
<button id="getValue">Get value</button>


ko.applyBindings();

$("#getValue").click(function() {
    alert($("#textArea").find("textarea").val());
});
```

But I don't see any reason to act this way having much cleaner approaches.

Comment: Thank you!!! Think I had gone mad! But your **var val = $("#textArea").dxTextArea("instance").option("value");** Really helped in getting the value into a 'usable' variable! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div
    id="myTextArea"
    data-bind="dxTextArea: {showClearButton: true,value: 'MyTests'}">
    CONTENT
</div>
 <div
    data-bind="dxButton: { text: 'Save text' }"
    onclick="saveMyData('myTextArea')">TEXT TO CLICK
 </div>

<script>
    function saveMyData(objID) {
        if (obj = document.getElementById(objID))
        {
            alert(obj.innerHTML);
            obj.innerHTML = obj.innerHTML + " MORE TEXT.. ";
        } else
        {
            alert("Object with ID " + objID + " not found");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Maybe this helps you:http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q461148

Comment: This prints **[objectHTMLDivElement]** - not the text that was inputted :(

Comment: unfortunately, this may work with a 'normal' **textArea**, but it doesn't seem to with a **dxTextArea** ?

Comment: those methods are available, but still doesn't give me the text within the **dxTextArea** - God, i miss developing in C#!!!

Comment: as dxTextArea documentation tells you, you should use ".value" - try obj.value instead of .innerHTML.

Comment: @jbutler483 C# is for amateurs :p Wolfgang, he first has to use the observable to update the value otherwise his value will be always empty. What you could try is to start with a default value. This should give you some result.

Comment: @GuyT - i think you are right. I have no idea to the dx... "Framework", thought it's a "normal" Javascript Problem. :D

Comment: @GuyT - I've used the ko.observable - but there isn' a clear way of actually *updating* this on user input. It's back to square one really :(